# Is it safe to have an external function from unmanaged code that returns an int

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

```
[DllImport(MyUnmanagedLibrary, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int MyFunction();
```

Let's say this is a function that I import from an unmanaged C++ library. In this instance the external function is declared as returning an `int`. The size of `int` does not change in managed C# code, but it does change depending on the architecture in unmanaged C++ code. Is it safe to assume that it returns an `int`? Should I use `IntPtr` instead, as the return value? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` in C# is and will always be `System.Int32`, the point is that every C++ compiler is (in theory) free to do whatever it wants with types sizes (within certain limits), so, if you want to avoid a mismatch, you should change the C++ side of code, making it return a fixed-size integer (e.g. `int32_t`). `IntPtr` cannot help, since `int` is not defined to have the size of a pointer (and actually, on x86_64 Windows `int` is 32 bit, while `int *` is 64 bit).

On the other hand, it's *extremely* unlikely that any compiler on x86 Windows will ever define `int` as anything different than a 32 bit 2's-complement integer, for obvious binary compatibility reasons.

Comment: And what about x64 systems? Do you think this would cause a problem?

Comment: Again, the C++ compiler can do whatever it wants, but typically `int` remains 32 bit (on x86_64 Windows you have 32 bit `int` and `long`, 64 bit `long long`, on Linux 32 bit `int`, 64 bit `long` and `long long`). But, again, the only way to be sure is to force the use of a fixed width type on the C++ side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then it's unlikely to cause any problems, I'll stop my micro-optimization attempt here :)

Comment: Ensuring correctness isn't "optimization".  Changing the C++ code to use a fixed-size type like `int32_t` is a good idea.

Comment: Ok then I have stopped my "micro ensuring-correctness" attempt there. Thanks for the confirmation though.

Comment: `int` on Windows x86 and x64 is always 32 bits wide. That's in the ABI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the compiler option with "-m32" or "-m64" for g++ for example. More specific [choose the best match](http://ae-www.technion.ac.il/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=all&topic=g%2b%2b) based on your "Machine Dependent Options"

Comment: `-m32` and `-m64` set the target architecture, the size of types is only a byproduct of this (also, g++'s `int` is 32 bit on both x86 and x86_64)..

Comment: by default it will be chosen based on the target.